# Understanding Avdi's objects on rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm reading through Avdi's [objects on rails book](http://objectsonrails.com/#sec-5-2) and don't understand a section of sample code.

He creates a class like so I guess for dependency injection purposes:

```
class Blog
  # ...
  attr_writer :post_source
  # ...
  private
  def post_source
    @post_source ||= Post.public_method(:new)
  end
end
```

Then he writes the following spec

```
# spec/models/blog_spec.rb
require 'ostruct'
describe Blog do
  # ...
  describe "#new_post" do
    before do
      @new_post = OpenStruct.new
      @it.post_source = ->{ @new_post }
    end
    it "returns a new post" do
      @it.new_post.must_equal @new_post
    end
    it "sets the post's blog reference to itself" do
      @it.new_post.blog.must_equal(@it)
    end
  end
end
```

I don't understand why he uses `@it.post_source = ->{ @new_post }`

Why didn't he just use something like `@it.post_source = OpenStruct.public_method(:new)` which would be similar to his Blog class code which has `@post_source ||= Post.public_method(:new)`

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: I welcome questions like this on the book's [discussion list](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/objects-on-rails)! I or one of the other 500+ members will be happy to try and explain, and the answers will then benefit other readers as well :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`->{ @new_post }` is a lambda that returns the instance stored in @new_post.

`Post.public_method(:new)` would return the constructor method of Post

Passing in the lambda for the class to use lets you have control of the instance that is returned. Passing in a class' constructor means you don't know what instance it will get, just that it will be of the class you specified.

Comment: Isn't that kind of what I said?

Comment: Maybe Dave. I'm sorry I couldn't understand your answer. I got lost in the pronouns.

Answer (score 0):

It provides a reference for the `it` spec, otherwise it couldn't be compared in the `it "returns a new post"` block. It uses the simple dependency injection mechanism allowed in the `post_source` method to ease testability.

Comment: Wouldn't `@new_post_source = OpenStruct.public_method(:new); @it.post_source = @new_post_source`, then ? I still don't really get the whereabouts of using a lambda. (Excepts for what Nigel Thorne said, but why would we care about what instance we will get ? As long as we have an instance, for the sake of this particular test.)

Comment: @Paperwork Yes, that's what's basically in the code now--grabbing the method is (more or less?) the same as as putting it in a lambda. We care *what* instance we get because we refer to it later.